# How to connect to Docker container with localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, wsl-2, docker-for-windows

I am running a **mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server** docker container for local development that works perfectly on one machine.

But on my laptop the container is sometimes inaccessible.

If I try to connect through SQL Server Management Studio I can connect through **localhost**, **[::1]**, **127.0.0.1** or **"."**. This works perfectly.

But if I run **sqlcmd**, **dotnet** or **Azure Data Studio**, only **127.0.0.1** and **[::1]** connections will work.

When I try to connect to **localhost** or **"."**, I get the message:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I could change my behavior to only work with 127.0.0.1, but this requires me to change a bunch of project files where I am working on with a larger team.

I have searched online and found that localhost sometimes does not work for WSL 2. But I have successfully tested my WSL 2 setup and as said before I am able to connect with SQL Server Management Studio.

I have also tried disabling my Firewall.

Comment: have you tried `-S tcp:localhost,1433` - I believe this will force TCP instead of named pipes

Comment: Seems that it's trying to use the `Named Pipes Provider` by default. If you have the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager tool installed then go to the Client Protocols configuration screens (for both 32- and 64-bit clients) and either change the priorities so that the `TCP/IP` protocol has the highest priority or disable the `Names Pipes` protocol.

Comment: I had to install SQL Server 2019 to access **SQL Server Configuration Manager**, afterward the Client Protocols configuration screen order was: `1: Shared Memory`, `2: TCP/IP`, `3: Named Pipes`. I have disabled 1 and 3 so that `TCP/IP` remains. but the **Docker SQL container** keeps having the issue.

As an interesting bonus; if I start the SQL Server development edition, I am able to connect to `localhost`.

Comment: I have gotten a little farther with this issue. It seems that when I try to connect to localhost, the target IP address is actually that of my mobile 4G adapter.

While the remote IP address should actually map to 127.0.0.1.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my laptop has a second network adapter connected to the internet. That is actually a 4G sim card connection.

When using [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) I found out that connecting to localhost did not redirect to 127.0.0.1 but the IP address of the 4G adapter.

This was not picked up by com.docker.backend.exe since it only accepts connections trough my first network adapter.

For the time I have turned of my 4G connection when I am working from a Wifi connection. If I have the time I will try to find out how I can change the priority for a localhost call to my network devices.